# Why does Sublime Text show "untitled (Desktop)" in the title bar?

Tags: sublime-text-3

When I open any (or no) file in Sublime Text, it shows "untitled **(Desktop)**" in the title bar. What does '(Desktop)' mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (Desktop) means that you have a folder open on your desktop. You can trigger the Side Bar using `CTRL+K, CTRL+B`. You can also remove the folder by right-clicking on it and selecting `Remove Folder from Project`.

Comment: If you press Alt+tab still you can see the ```untitled```